# Как обработать NullPointerException java?

Tags: java

Всем привет! Есть такой кусок кода

```
public void outputFigures(String[] args) throws IOException {
        if (args.length != 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Некорректное количество (%d) аругментов! Должен быть 1 аргумент", args.length));
        }
```

Если я вызову этот метод например так -

```
outputFigures(null);
```

то у меня полетит NPE, пробую обработать его таким способом

```
if(args == null){throw new NullPointerException("bla bla bla");}
```

но все равно получаю null. Как мне сделать так чтобы отобразилось bla bla bla?

Comment: где получаете `null`? где вы хотите чтобы отобразилось "bla bla bla"

Comment: null в консоли, надо чтобы в консоль пользовательское сообщение bla bla вывелось

Comment: у вас же нигде нет вывода в консоль(добавьте в вопрос)

Comment: я это исключение ловлю выше, т.е. оттуда где вызываю этот метод (в  main), соответственно вывод в консоль там же - System.out.printl(e.getMessage())

Comment: вы уверены, что ловится именно это исключение? Всё должно работать нормально

Answer (score 0):

Неправильно самостоятельно генерировать NPE. Если вам нужно провалидировать, что входной аргумент не null, то опять же лучше использовать IllegalArgumentExeption.

Comment: Я все равно получаю на выходе null вместо bla bla bla

Comment: Пробую как то так - args[0] == null, args.equals(null), результат один и тот же - null

Answer (score 0):

Все, понял!)) Нужно if поменять местами - сначала проверка на null, затем все остальное!)

Comment: Приведите окончательные вариант кода в ответе.